# My VBA code for a textbox does not include the final input in the cell value

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = TextBox1.Value
    If Not (KeyAscii >= 48 And KeyAscii <= 57) Then
        KeyAscii = 0
        MsgBox "Digits only"
    End If
End Sub
```

Code is used on a textbox in a userform.

I received some help yesterday and got this helpful piece of VBA code which works nicely. However, there is a slight bug with this. The textbox is supposed to only accept digits (hence the `KeyAscii >= 48 And KeyAscii <= 57`) however the last input digit does not get converted to the cell.

For instance, when you type "1234" in the textbox, it only writes "123" in the cell and omits the last digit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This subroutine is being activated upon the keypress, so they key hasn't registered as a entry into the textbox yet.

You can concatenate the last character (keypress character) onto your cell value though:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = TextBox1.Value & chr(KeyAscii)
    If Not (KeyAscii >= 48 And KeyAscii <= 57) Then
        KeyAscii = 0
        MsgBox "Digits only"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @WoeIs side note, I would just eat the illegal keypress - popping a `MsgBox` is just annoying... just put a label somewhere near the textbox that makes it clear that the box expects digits.

Comment: Also the `Chr(KeyAscii)` shouldn't be concatenated if the key is illegal... I'd just put that line in a `TextBox.Change` handler (i.e. after the actual content has changed)

Comment: Totally agree with that last comment @MathieuGuindon. That first line of the sub would do better inside an `Else`.